# FreePBX BLF Webhook

Tags: freepbx

When starting a call, a link should be called.
Likewise, a link should be triggered as soon as the call is ended.

Can someone tell me where I can store this?

FreePBX

BLF Webhook Link

I am very grateful for any kind of help
I am very grateful for any kind of help
I am very grateful for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

It has no any relation to BLF.

You can either check AMI/ARI events or setup hangup/answer handlers in dialplan.

Both topic can't be described in one page answer